# "The upload path does not appear to be valid" Codeigniter image upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

This has been asked a lot but after trying a number of things, I still can't find a solution to my cause of this issue.

I'm autoloading the upload library.

My folder structure is:

```
/application/
/assets/
    css/
    images/
        hero/
    js/
/system/
```

My controller:

```
$fileName = $this->input->post('title') . '_hero';
$filePath = './assets/images/hero/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['overwrite'] = true;

$this->upload->initialize($config);

if (!empty($_FILES['heroimage'])) {
    $config['file_name'] = $fileName;
    $config['upload_path'] = $filePath;

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('heroimage')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        var_dump($error);
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

I have tried initializing both how it is now and using `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` but neither have worked.

I have also checked if the directory exists and if it is writable and both returned true.

Another thing I tried was setting the upload path to `$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'assets\images\hero';`

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have config data like because the file path was not initialized

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences

```
$fileName = $this->input->post('title') . '_hero';
$filePath = './assets/images/hero/';
$config['upload_path'] = $filePath;
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['overwrite'] = true;

$this->upload->initialize($config);

if (!empty($_FILES['heroimage'])) {

  if (!$this->upload->do_upload('heroimage')) {

       // errors

  } else {

       $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

       echo $upload_data['file_name'];

  }
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* this was the issue. It was late last night!